# Django form not refreshing once updated

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Iam working in django forms using python.
Iam facing an issue while saving editform.

If iam saving the form with charfield and textfield changes, its working fine(refreshing with the updated content).
But if i save the form by changing the imagefield and charfield, its updating but not refreshing the page.

I want the page to be refreshed once the details updated or saved.
Thanks in Advance.

MY VIEWS.PY:

```
def profile_page(request,type = None):
    profile_list = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, visit_id = request.user.username, profile_type = type)
    image = UserProfile.objects.get(visit_id = request.user.username, profile_type = type).image
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            if new_image == None:
                current_image=form.fields['image'].initial = profile_list.image
            else:
                person = UserenaSignup.objects.get(visitid = request.user.username).id
                UserImage.objects.filter(username = person, profile_type = type).delete()
                current_image = UserImage.objects.create(username_id = person, profile_type = type, image = form.cleaned_data['image']).image
            UserProfile.objects.filter(visit_id = request.user.username, profile_type = type).update(username            = form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                                                                                  designation            = form.cleaned_data['designation'],
                                                                                                  image                  = current_image,
                                                                                 )
            return render_to_response('profile_page.html',locals(),context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        else:
            form = UserProfileForm(instance = profile_list)
            return render_to_response('profile_page.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance = profile_list)
    return render_to_response('profile_page.html',locals(),context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove `.image` from the end of this line:

```
current_image = UserImage.objects.create(username_id = person, profile_type = type, image = form.cleaned_data['image']).image
```